# Need to implement Push Notification to push messages to Desktop Client (not web/browser)

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, asmx, push-notification

I need to make a Desktop Application (.NET/ C#) which will reside in the system tray. Its function is to receive push notification from the server and then to display it to the user. I have a webservice (again in .NET/ C# ASMX) running @ my server side which is polling db continuously for changes, so ultimately my webservice always have the updated/changed data.

Can you suggest any existing framework or workaround according to my scenario which can allow me to send push notifications from server to my desktop client?

Answer (score 0):

For an application that we developed, I used .NET Remoting to do server-push.

The server runs as a Windows Service and clients attach to it via remoting.  Once registered, the server can push messages out to the desktop.  This eliminates the need for polling.

Once the user's app receives word from the server that it needs to refresh, it can then call your webservice to fetch the data.

Comment: Hey jfuhr! Thanks for your quick reply :) Your idea seems to be fine. But I guess it will make me code from the scratch to implement this! Is there any such already implemented and proven framework available?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is the implementation of the Observer Design Pattern. Here is a pretty good documentation from MSDN regarding this. It is a rather advanced .NET programming topic, but something really worth looking at.

- [Observer Design Pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee850490.aspx)

Regards,

Huske

Comment: Huske Thanks for your reply :) I guess this will work for me! Only problem I can see is it need .NET Framework 4.0 (minimum) and if I opt .NET 4.0 then my app won't run on XP SP2 and previous versions.